# Extract Data from Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I want to extract data in red boxes under column name (highlighted in green) under tab name (colored in yellow) from multiple workbooks using wildcard and end name (highlighted in blue). my code stopped after creating a workbook. (code below) and formatting it. please help on how can i get all data until last data

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim JCN As String, Path As String

UserForm1.Hide

JCN = TextBox3.Value

ReportName = JCN & " PANEL NESTING REPORT"

UserName = Environ$("Username")

Path = "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Desktop\"

Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "NESTING REPORT"

'Column Header
Range("B1").Value = "WBS Code"
Range("C1").Value = "Airline Code"
Range("D1").Value = "JCN"
Range("E1").Value = "'3000LVL"
Range("F1").Value = "MBOM"
Range("G1").Value = "Make Part"
Range("H1").Value = "LAV"
Range("I1").Value = "LC Number"
Range("J1").Value = "Rev"
Range("K1").Value = "Size"
Range("L1").Value = "Part Number"
Range("M1").Value = "Rev"
Range("N1").Value = "Qty"
Range("O1").Value = "Classification"
Range("P1").Value = "Type"
Range("Q1").Value = "Thickness"
Range("R1").Value = "Rawmat"
Range("S1").Value = "Remarks"
Range("T1").Value = "'.400 Code"
Range("U1").Value = "W.O."

'Format Column Header
Range("B1:U1").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
    .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
Columns("B:U").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

'Extract Data





'Save Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & ReportName & ".xlsx"

'Close Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my code stopped after creating a workbook"? Do you get an error? Furthermore it is not clear from where you run the code? Please read [ask] and [repro] - this should help you to improve your question.

Comment: no error. i don't have code for the nest step which is getting the data from other workbooks.

Comment: But still What does "my code stopped after creating a workbook"? What would you expect the code to do after "it stopped"?